# How do I create an Empty ShapeStyle?

Tags: swiftui

Whenever an API expects a `View` but you don't have one, you can pass an [`EmptyView()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/emptyview). I'm looking for the equivalent, but for [`ShapeStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle).

For example, imagine I want to add a border to a view conditionally:

```
myView
  .border(showBorder ? myShapeStyle : EmptyShapeStyle())
```

I just made up `EmptyShapeStyle` though so, it doesn't work.

Is there a way to produce an empty `ShapeStyle`?

---

I know I could do:

```
if showBorder {
  myView
    .border(myShapeStyle)
} else {
  myView
}
```

But I want to avoid repeating the `myView` bit and introducing an `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the style you want here is `ShapeStyle.clear` (which is also `Color.clear`). Is there a case where EmptyShapeStyle would behave differently?